# determine work group count for particle system opengl

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, compute-shader

What is the correct way to determine the global work group size and local work group size for compute shader?

And how can the 2nd dimension be used (num_groups_y).
Can I pass an array of vectors and index them using gl_GlobalInvocationID.y ?

My requirement has 100k particles and I am passing another array of vectors for position calculation.
For my Particle Position is GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER
and for the array of vectors I am using uniform.

Is it possible to index the array of vectors using gl_GlobalInvocationID.y by passing the array size in gl_DispatchCompute ?
And what should be the optimal num_groups_x value to be set?

Comment: please avoid using words like *lakh* that are not globally understood